# My laptop runs very hot with Lubuntu 11.10, what can I do?

Tags: lubuntu, thinkpad

What are my options?  Can I make the fans run more, can I make the CPU do less work, is it my graphics card?
IBM T60 with Core Duo, ATI graphics

Thanks

Comment: Some has the same problem, it may be a problem with ubuntu's fan control. or maybe a bad process taking too mush resources. try TOP command in the terminal and take a look at the highest process

Comment: It's a long shot and I'll recommend you try everything else before, but there might be a bug in the kernel (I know there was a problem like this with the Linux Mint 11 LXDE) and you can resolve it with an upgrade. But I repeat, it's a long shot.

Comment: used top, the only thing using a lot of cpu/memory is chromium.  Everything else is negligible.  I should add that it doesn't seem like it's going to catastrophically overheat, it's just uncomfortable to the touch.

Comment: and the kernel I have is 3.0.0-17-generic

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a long shot that an upgrade would fix the overheating.  3.0 kernel is well-known by now for power-management issues.  The problem is that upgrading may cause other problems.  If you have other things wrong with your laptop, then you might consider 12.04.  You can even wait one week for the release.

Comment: is it easy to upgrade to the next version?  Like, can I just go into the update manager when the release happens and move to the new Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/110483/43660) for a screenshot of what you should see.

Comment: Ok cool thanks a lot!  I'm also going to try the fglrx drivers as suggested below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you (and I)  have the same problem as most users using Intel processors. There is a power regression/overheating bug with Linux kernel used by 11.10. Good news is this bug has been fixed as witnessed by 12.04 beta 2 users.

Just upgrade to 12.04 on April 26 which I'm sure will take care of this problem once and for all. Hope this helps!

Comment: You are welcome. Trust me I know frustrating this is. 12.04 I read has dealt with it.

Comment: @jones, so how did it go, did the heating problem get solved in more recent versions?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing lastest propietary drivers for your ATI graphics, Open-Source drivers are known to make some cards (especially on laptops), work at higher temperatures, Catalyst 12.3 or later could fix this overheating problem.

ej. In my laptop, temperature went from 75°C to 44°C with propietary drivers.

Comment: How can I install the proprietary ones?  I looked in the "Additional Drivers" under Preferences, but there's no way to add/change the graphics driver

Comment: Can you specify which graphics cards does your computer have?